# Unusual requests in IIS logs and .net website crashing

Tags: .net, debugging, iis-6

Our large .net site is crashing with reports of CPU spikes. In IIS 6.0 I can see hundreds of unusual requests in logs as below. Any ideas about these requests? thanks

> 2013-12-25 17:34:29 W3SVC1 xx.246.105.xxxx GET /default.aspx authResp=fo5EWSS5Pc6HkDcmDGcL7qi9COCp2payZpRsDKiTJ/ISIwFRq6KvodMp2edRlYv7EVqECodecI+UwSZAZYmCFADiX4RhTjoq05sGq8Sh/DVjjHsx7B0SaL0aFMcyLLft 80 - 5.19.252.234 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/4.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0) 404 0 0
>
> 2013-12-25 17:34:29 W3SVC1 xx.246.105.xxxx GET /default.aspx
>   authResp=fo5EWSS5Pc6HkDcmDGcL7sb4D41lKIID4xojrUh0JHgEnIGJUCJYrf+mCcAeFQnXz122mWIDVgG6x+vtqCInfKNEqcB/4AiAynao4P2KZch/bGVbriFLbrjUYiyqMyst
>   80 - 5.76.233.138
>   Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/4.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0)
>   404 0 64
>
> 2013-12-25 17:34:29 W3SVC1 xx.246.105.xxxx GET /default.aspx
>   authResp=fo5EWSS5Pc6HkDcmDGcL7sb4D41lKIID4xojrUh0JHgEnIGJUCJYrf+mCcAeFQnXz122mWIDVgG6x+vtqCInfKNEqcB/4AiAynao4P2KZch/bGVbriFLbrjUYiyqMyst
>   80 - 87.252.227.9
>   Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/4.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0)
>   404 0 0
>
> 2013-12-25 17:34:29 W3SVC1 xx.246.105.xxxx GET /default.aspx
>   authResp=fo5EWSS5Pc6HkDcmDGcL7qi9COCp2payZpRsDKiTJ/ISIwFRq6KvodMp2edRlYv7EVqECodecI+UwSZAZYmCFADiX4RhTjoq05sGq8Sh/DVjjHsx7B0SaL0aFMcyLLft
>   80 - 94.179.47.15
>   Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/4.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0)
>   404 0 0

Comment: What is unusual about those requests?

Comment: Never seen in our site logs authresp "authResp=fo5EWSS5Pc6HkDcmDGcL7qi9COCp2payZpRsDKiTJ/ISIwFRq6KvodMp2edRlYv7EVqECodecI+UwSZAZYmCFADiX4RhTjoq05sGq8Sh/DVjjHsx7B0SaL0aFMcyLLft 80"